# using strcat more than 1 time - link2019

Tags: c, string, visual-studio, strcpy, strcat

I'm trying to use strcat 2 time in a row.
when I compile first 2 lines it's works, but when I added the third line I get:
    "Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _srtcat referenced in function _StartUpFunc "

```
strcpy(msg2sent, "Hello");
strcat(msg2sent, temp_username);
srtcat(msg2sent, ", welcome to the session.");
```

what can be the reason?
Im using VS15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third time, you spelled it `srtcat`. Correct to `strcat`.

Comment: I wish all bugs were this easy!

Comment: Cant believe it happeaned to me lol, tnx! :)

Comment: If you compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, you would get a more pertinent diagnostic for invoking an unprototyped function... Actually you seem to use Microsoft tools, maybe `-W4` can help.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on the third line: `srtcat` instead of `strcat`.